# Array php não exibindo chave com mesmo valor

Tags: php, array

Tenho um array de hours(horas) e outro de schedule(agenda). Quando um cliente marca uma consulta, essa hora vai para o array de agenda. 2 Clientes marcaram as 08hrs, 3 clientes as 09hrs ... igual esta no array agenda. Aí quero retirar das horas quando um horário chegar no limite de atendimento. Por exemplo: Se eu determinar que no horário das 09hrs so podem ter 3 atendimentos, na proxima listagem de horas esse horario das 09hrs não pode aparecer mais e isso esta funcionando perfeitamente até esse ponto. Mas se repetir duas quantidades de consultas em horarios diferentes ele so retira um aleatorio e precisava retirar os dois com mesma quantidade de consultas marcadas.

Exemplo:

08:00 = 2 consultas marcadas;

09:00 = 3 consultas marcadas;

mas se as 10:00 horas também tiver 3 consultas marcadas ele retira ou os da 09hrs ou 10hrs e eu preciso retirar os dois se repetir a quantidade determinada por mim. Alguém poderia me auxiliar?

[Segue o código](https://pastebin.com/pB8vDVHZ):

```
// horários que são exibidos para os clientes
$hours        = array('08:00','08:30','09:00','09:30','10:00','10:30','11:00','11:30','12:00','12:30','13:00','13:30','14:00');

// horários que os clientes marcaram
$schedule     = array('08:00','08:00','09:00','09:00','09:00','10:00','10:00','10:00','10:00','11:00','11:00','11:00','11:00','11:00' );

// ao chegar nesse valor de consultas agendada por horário é retirado o horário do array hours
$chooseNumber = 5;

$count        = array_count_values( $schedule );
foreach( $count as $number => $value )
{

    if( $value > 1 )
    {
        $schedules[$value] = $number;

        if( $value == $chooseNumber )
        {
             $newHours[$value] = $number;
        }

     }


}
echo "<pre>";
print_r( $schedules );
echo "</pre>";

echo "<pre>";
print_r( array_diff( $hours, $newHours ) );
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: desculpa pela maneira que postei. Ainda não acostumei com a maneira do stack para formular perguntas. Mas poderia me auxiliar nesse código?

Comment: como faço para colocar como resolvido?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu faria assim:

(código está comentado)

```
// ao chegar nesse valor de consultas agendada por horário é retirado o horário do array hours
$chooseNumber = 3;

$count        = array_count_values( $schedule );
$array_com_horarios_livres = array();

foreach($hours as $hour){
    # SE O HORÁRIO EM $hours ESTIVERM EM $count E A QUANTIDADE FOR MAIOR OU IGUAL AO LIMITE CONTINUE O LOOP SEM INSERIR
    if(isset($count[$hour]) && $count[$hour] >= $chooseNumber)
        continue;
    $array_com_horarios_livres[] = $hour; # INSERE NO NOVO ARRAY COM OS HORÁRIOS LIVRES
}

print_r($array_com_horarios_livres);
```

**[Veja funcionando no Ideone](https://ideone.com/uNvjFP)**

Comment: Muito obrigado, perfeito!

Comment: @ThiagoMoreira não esquece de aprovar por favor!

Comment: como faço para aprovar?

Comment: @ThiagoMoreira no canto esquerdo no topo da **resposta** tem um sinal de  ↑ (up) e ↓ (down)   para você avaliar a resposta... Embaixo disso tem um sinal de ✔ para você marcar como resposta certa.

Comment: Obrigado, feita aprovação!!

Answer (score 0):

O problema está nessa parte:

```
if( $value == $chooseNumber )
    {
         $newHours[$value] = $number;
    }
```

pois no momento que tu faz o array newHours e coloca em $value, se tu tiver dois com o mesmo valor ex:
9:00,9:00,11:00,11:00
sera colocado o 9 a primeira vez depois como o value sera o mesmo anterior o 11 ira substituir na mesma posição.
como tu sabe exatamente a posição que precisa tirar é só dentro do teu if colocar um unset

```
if( $value == $chooseNumber )
    {
        unset($hours[$number]);
    }
```

e no fim tu só da

print_r($hours)

Comment: obrigado Gabriella